# Can't install Data Migration Tool on Magento 2.1.7 with PHP 7.1.17

Tags: php, magento, composer-php

I need to migrate data from Magento 1.9.2.4 to 2.1.7 exactly using php7.1

I have Ubuntu 17.10

Php 7.1.17

I've installed Magento 2.1.7 already on php7.1.17, but i can't install Data Migration Tool..

I've been run this

```
composer config repositories.magento composer ttps://repo.magento.com
```

then this

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.7

    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      Password: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
Do you want to store credentials for repo.magento.com in /home/sky/.composer/auth.json ? [Yn] y
./composer.json has been updated                                  
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                     
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 100.1.7) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.7].
```

but get that exception...

Can anybody help me, plz?

That's my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.7",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.7",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/phpmodule-customer-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/sample-data-media": "100.1.*",
    "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.1.7"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "data-migration-tool": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool"
    },
    "magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}

Comment: show composer.json file code

Comment: Just a heads up: Ubuntu 17.10 is EOL since July this year. Consider upgrading so the OS keeps getting updates and security fixes.

Comment: @Loek I need to use ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.1 isn't compatible with PHP 7.1 according to the official docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

That's probably the problem. Consider moving to a newer version of Magento (2.2 does support PHP 7.1) or downgrade your PHP version. Personally I'd go for the former.

Comment: I need magento 2.1.7 and php 7.1

Comment: Okay, but they simply don't work together. Either rewrite PHP 7.1 to be compatible with Magento 2.1 or rewrite Magento 2.1 to be compatible with PHP 7.1. They just don't work together out of the box.

Comment: But i've installed magento 2.1.7 with php 7.1.17, and one man say he did my question before.. maybe there some tricks like that?

Comment: Have you actually installed it? Cause that error message looks a lot like "Magento can not be installed" to me...

Comment: I used this topic https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139634/magento-2-1-1-not-compatibile-with-php-7-1-0 so yes i did it

Comment: It literally says in the answers that Magento 2.1 is *not* compatible with PHP 7.1? And that Magento 2.2 is the version to use?

Comment: But the trick worked for me and for the author of the question, answered by Konstantin Gerasimov

Comment: So you hacked your way around the install of the framework. Wouldn't recommend it but okay. This means you've got to hack your way around the install of every plugin you need. So you gotta find out what's to be done about the data migration plugin and install it. Mind you, this is for every update you want to do. I really recommend upgrading Magento or downgrading PHP as this is a rabbit hole you don't want to be in.